# Preload a layer during page load with Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, layer, preload

I have a leaflet map with five geojson layers (baseMaps) and i control them by a L.control. My third layer contains many points to visualize so when i click on it, it takes a lot of time to load.

Is there a way to preload this layer specifically, even if the entire page takes a litlle bit more time to load ?

Thanks

Comment: If your layer group has hundreds to thousands points, it is the DOM rendering process that takes time. You may be interested in clustering or canvas plugins to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have 4 layers with only chrolopleth maps and just one with ~8000 points. And i forgot to mention that but my points are already clusterize.

Comment: How do you manage the crowded layer loading? Please share some code (bonus point: reproduce your issue online, e.g. using JSFiddle, JSBin, Plunker…) so that we can help you.

Comment: Additionally, which clustering plugin do you use, and what is its version? Be noted that Leaflet.markercluster plugin got a major performance improvement in its latest version.

Comment: i'm using 0.4.0 version of the leaflet.markercluster plugin. I will set a jsfiddle !

Comment: Make sure to use the latest version of Leaflet.markercluster from [leaflet-0.7 branch](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/tree/leaflet-0.7).

Comment: Ok I downloaded latest version and i think it loads faster. I'll always check latest version now ! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) computes the clustering only once it is added to a map (it needs to know the map configuration in order to process the clustering).

As said in the question comments, the first step is to use the latest version of that plugin, as it benefits from a major performance upgrade compared to version 0.4.0.

If you still want the plugin to process the clustering in advance, so that the user does not have to wait the first time he/she clicks on the Layers Control, a workaround would be to add your clustered layered to map and to remove it immediately: that way, the clustering is processed at initialization, and the layer is ready for display once the user wants to see it.